# Chrome extension content script

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I want to use a plugin on the content page, this is my code :

manifest

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "foo",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "options_ui": {

        "page": "options.html",

        "chrome_style": true

    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "https://google.com/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://google.com/*"],
        "js": ["jquery-3.1.0.min.js", "simply-toast.min.js"],
        "css": ["simply-toast.min.css"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }]
}
```

content.js

```
...

$.simplyToast('success', 'This is a success message!'); // Line 72
```

jQuery works fine but I get this error when trying simpleToast `content.js:72 Uncaught TypeError: $.simplyToast is not a function` .Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: `I get this error when trying simpleToast` - where are you trying it? There's no content script of your own declared in manifest.json. Also, why `http://` and not `https://`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong Syntax I guess!

```
$.simplyToast('This is a success message', 'success'); // Line 72
```